# Google cloud credentials retrieve private key from azure vault

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently we put the google cloud credentials in json file and set it via GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

But we do not want to hardcode the private key in the json file due to security reasons. We want to put the private key in Azure key vault (yes we use azure key Vault), is there a way to provide the credentials programatically to GCP. so that i can read azure key vault and provide the private key via code. I tried to check and use `GoogleCredentials` and googles `DefaultCredentialsProvider` etc classes, but i could not find a proper example.

Note: The google credentials type is Service Credential

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I understand that you run your code on Google Cloud and you want to get a service account key file from azure key fault, correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Store the service account JSON base64 encoded in Azure Key Vault as a string.
2. Read the string back from Key Vault and base64 decode back to a JSON string.
3. Load the JSON string using one of the SDK member methods with names similar to **from_service_account_info()** (Python SDK).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i use java. I stored only private key in keyvault and rest of the attributes like client id , client email, token uri etc in application properties file and in code using ServiceAccountCredentials class, constructed the credentials and used in BigqueryBuilder. Things are working fine

Comment: @KalaiselvamM The Client Secret must be protected. Do not store that secret in application properties.

Comment: I can't find a "from_service_account_info() in the Firebase Admin SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin  Which is the one Google documentation seems to point you towards using. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: @Reddspark - Each product/service SDK can have its own style. Which language? I recommend posting a new question. For Node.js in-memory credentials are specified this way: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.credential_n.md#example_2

Answer (score 0):

John's answer is the correct one if you want to load a secret from Azure vault.

However, if you need a service account credential in Google Cloud environment, you don't need a service account key file, you can use the automatically loaded service account into the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview)

In almost all Google Cloud service, you can customize the service account to use. In the worse case, you need to use the default service account for the context, and grant it the correct permissions.

Service account key file use isn't a good practice on Google Cloud product. It's a long lived credential, and you have to rotate yourselves, keep it secrets,...

Answer (score 0):

We use something like this in java to create Bigquery from credential details

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;

ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.newBuilder()
                .setClientId()
                .setClientEmail()
                .setPrivateKey() 
                .setPrivateKeyId()
                .setProjectId()
                .setTokenServerUri()
                .build();
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(serviceAccountCredentials)
                .build()
                .getService();
```